# Pipe string with newline to command in bash?

Tags: bash

I am trying to pass in a string containing a newline to a PHP script via BASH.

```
#!/bin/bash

REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"

message=$(svnlook log $REPOS -r $REV)
changed=$(svnlook changed $REPOS -r $REV)

/usr/bin/php -q /home/chad/www/mantis.localhost/scripts/checkin.php <<< "${message}\n${changed}"
```

When I do this, I see the literal "\n" rather than the escaped newline:

```
blah blah issue 0000002.\nU app/controllers/application_controller.rb
```

Any ideas how to translate '\n' to a literal newline?

By the way: what does <<< do in bash? I know < passes in a file...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

try

```
echo -e "${message}\n${changed}" | /usr/bin/php -q /home/chad/www/mantis.localhost/scripts/checkin.php
```

where -e enables interpretation of backslash escapes (according to `man echo`)

Note that this will also interpret backslash escapes which you potentially have in `${message}` and in `${changed}`.

---

From the bash manual:
  Here Strings

A variant of here documents, the format is:

```
<<<word
```

The word is expanded and supplied to the command on its standard input.

So I'd say

```
the_cmd <<< word
```

is equivalent to

```
echo word | the_cmd
```

Comment: Nice! It's actually -e rather than -a, but that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: yes, you're right, I was thinking -e but typing -a... I'll correct this.

Comment: `the_cmd <<< word` isn’t *quite* equivalent to `echo word | the_cmd`: `<<<` seems to be able to deal with longer strings.

Comment: BE AWARE: echo and heredoc prints a `\n` after the string. 
printf does not.
So instead of: 
`xargs -n1 -I% -d' ' echo "str: %" <<< "foo bar"`, 
do: 
`printf "foo bar" | xargs -n1 -I% -d' ' echo "str: %"`

Answer (score 4):

```
newline=$'\n'
... <<< "${message}${newline}${changed}"
```

The `<<<` is called a "here string". It's a one line version of the "here doc" that doesn't require a delimiter such as "EOF". This is a here document version:

```
... <<EOF
${message}${newline}${changed}
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

in order to avoid interpretation of potential escape sequences in `${message}` and `${changed}`, try concatenating the strings in a subshell (a newline is appended after each `echo` unless you specify the `-n` option):

```
( echo "${message}" ; echo "${changed}" ) | /usr/bin/php -q /home/chad/www/mantis.localhost/scripts/checkin.php
```

The parentheses execute the commands in a subshell (if no parentheses were given, only the output of the second echo would be piped into your php program).

Comment: "In order to avoid..." - that would be done if you used `echo -e`

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use here-document syntax:

```sh
cat <<EOF
copy $VAR1 $VAR2
del $VAR1
EOF
```

You can use magical Bash `$'\n'` with here-word:

```sh
cat <<< "copy $VAR1 $VAR2"$'\n'"del $VAR1"
```

or pipe with `echo`:

```sh
{ echo copy $VAR1 $VAR2; echo del $VAR1; } | cat
```

or with `printf`:

```sh
printf "copy %s %s\ndel %s" "$VAR1" "$VAR2" "$VAR1" | cat
```

Test it:

```sh
env VAR1=1 VAR2=2 printf "copy %s %s\ndel %s" "$VAR1" "$VAR2" "$VAR1" | cat
```